# Spark image deleted grom GCR gcr.io/spark-operator/spark:v3.1.1-hadoop3 any clones?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We been using this image gcr.io/spark-operator/spark:v3.1.1-hadoop3 from Google registry. Today I see that is gone. Does anybody knows where to find a copy of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it could have been affected by the deprecation of Container Registry,

It states effective May 15, 2023, Container Registry is deprecated. If you currently use Container Registry, you can transition to Artifact Registry.

You may check the documentation of Artifact registry on how to transition. Attached is the documentation.[1]

[1]

https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/transition/transition-from-gcr